# Will HTTP/2 work with Apache acting as a reverse proxy to an OpenLightSpeed server?

Tags: apache-2.2, http, litespeed

Before wasting my time and doing something I figured I would ask the question first. I really want to try out HTTP/2 and since Apache does not have a module for it yet I figured I would use OpenLiteSpeed.

My question is, if I use Apache as a reverse proxy to forward to another internal server will HTTP/2 work or not?

My current setup is all port 80, 443 traffic is forwarded to my Apache server at 192.168.168.2. I use the virtual hosts to forward traffic to a virtual machine on another server that is serving all the websites. I want to create another virtual machine and use OpenLight Speed with the HTTP/2 module and forward traffic from 192.168.168.2 to lets say 192.168.168.4 which would be the one with OpenLight Speed.

Hope I was clear enough for what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not work.

Think about an incoming client request and consider two questions:

1. which TCP connections are used?
2. what protocol is used on these TCP connections? ([the fine manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) might help.)